# Single command line parameter to control Topshelf windows service

Tags: c#, service, topshelf

I've made a topshelf windows service that starts three tasks. But since it might happen that one of those task might crash (yes, I know about `EnableServiceRecovery`), it would be better to use one program to create 3 services **with different names**  and install them using command line parameters.

So in theory the code would look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    // *********************Below is a TopShelf code*****************************//
    HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
    {
        hostConfigurator.Service<MyService>(serviceConfigurator =>
        {
            serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => new MyService(args[0])); //what service we are using
            serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(myService => myService.Start()); //what to run on start    
            serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(myService => myService.Stop()); // and on stop   
        });
        
        hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

        //****************Change those names for other services*******************************************//

        hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName("CallForwardService"+args[0]);
        hostConfigurator.SetDescription("CallForward using Topshelf"+args[0]);
        hostConfigurator.SetServiceName("CallForwardService"+args[0]);
        hostConfigurator.SetInstanceName(args[0]);
    });
}
```

But of course it won't, because (from what I've read) you can't simply use `args[]` but apparently you can use something like

```
Callforward.exe install --servicename:CallForward --instancename:Workshop
```

- I am still not sure how to pass the parameter to be used later in the program (in example above you can see it in `new MyService(args[0])`)
- Can I use single parameter to set up all three elements (name, instance and internal use)?

Comment: lol sounds like someone learned a variation on [Rubber Duck Decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using help from [How can I use CommandLine Arguments that is not recognized by TopShelf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004212/how-can-i-use-commandline-arguments-that-is-not-recognized-by-topshelf)

```
string department = null;
// *********************Below is a TopShelf code*****************************//
HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
{
    hostConfigurator.AddCommandLineDefinition("department", f => { department = f; });
    hostConfigurator.ApplyCommandLine();

    hostConfigurator.Service<MyService>(serviceConfigurator =>
    {
        serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => new MyService(department)); //what service we are using
        serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(myService => myService.Start()); //what to run on start    
        serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(myService => myService.Stop()); // and on stop   
    });

    hostConfigurator.EnableServiceRecovery(r => //What to do when service crashes
    {
        r.RestartService(0); //First, second and consecutive times
        r.RestartService(1);
        r.RestartService(1);

        r.SetResetPeriod(1); //Reset counter after 1 day
    });

    hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

    //****************Change those names for other services*******************************************//
    string d = "CallForwardService_" + department;

    hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName(d);
    hostConfigurator.SetDescription("CallForward using Topshelf");
    hostConfigurator.SetServiceName(d);
});
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29638241/2) to the question [Single command line parameter to control Topshelf windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638241/single-command-line-parameter-to-control-topshelf-windows-service) by the OP [Yasskier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1341244/yasskier) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>