# Topshelf - starting threads based on custom parameters

Tags: c#, topshelf

I've made a topshelf webservice that uses custom parameter:

```
string department = null;

// *********************Below is a TopShelf
HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
{
    //Define new parameter
    hostConfigurator.ApplyCommandLine();                                                
    //apply it  
    hostConfigurator.AddCommandLineDefinition("department", f => { department = f; });

    Helpers.LogFile("xxx", "Got department:"+department);  

    hostConfigurator.Service<MyService>(serviceConfigurator =>
    {
        //what service we are using
        serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => new MyService(department));
        //what to run on start
        serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(myService => myService.Start());
        // and on stop             
        serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(myService => myService.Stop());                 
    }

    hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalService();

    //****************Change those names for other
    string d = "CallForwardService_" + department;

    hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName(d);
    hostConfigurator.SetDescription("CallForward using Topshelf");
    hostConfigurator.SetServiceName(d);                
});



public class MyService
{
    string depTask;
    public MyService(string d)
    {
        //***********************Three tasks for three different destinations
        depTask = d;
        _taskL = new Task(Logistics);
        _taskP = new Task(Planners);
        _taskW = new Task(Workshop);
        Helpers.LogFile(depTask, "started working on threads for "+d);   

        public void Start()
        {
            if (depTask == "logistics")
            {
                _taskL.Start();
                Helpers.LogFile(depTask, "proper thread selected");      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `Helpers.logfile` simply writes to text file. Aa you can see from the code above the parameter `department` is passed to the `MyService(string d)`.
It all works fine when I'm debugging using i.e. the "-department:workshop" as debugging parameter. But when I'm trying to install the program as a service using
`callforward.exe install -department:logistics` I do create service `callforwardservice_logistics` bu when I check the log the parameter hasn't been passed to the MyService.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that by default Topshelf does not support adding custom parameters to the service start configuration and after installation the `ImagePath` value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyService` does not contain an additional parameter `-department:...`. You could inherit the default `WindowsHostEnvironment` and overload the `Install` method, but I think it would be easier (maybe less nicer) to just add the following code to your host configuration code:

```
// *********************Below is a TopShelf code*****************************//
HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
{
    ...
    hc.AfterInstall(ihc =>
    {
        using (RegistryKey system = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System"))
        using (RegistryKey currentControlSet = system.OpenSubKey("CurrentControlSet"))
        using (RegistryKey services = currentControlSet.OpenSubKey("Services"))
        using (RegistryKey service = services.OpenSubKey(ihc.ServiceName, true))
        {
            const String v = "ImagePath";
            var imagePath = (String)service.GetValue(v);
            service.SetValue(v, imagePath + String.Format(" -department \"{0}\"", department));
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a highly requested feature though, and would be a welcome pull request. I'm sure I will get to it eventually, it's just naught high on my radar at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue in the end: Setting up the parameter is not enough, you have to also create a named instance.

So in my case instead

```
callforward.exe install -department"logistics"
```

I've used

```
callforward.exe install -department"logistics" -instance:logistics
```

And then start the instance by the instance name:

```
net start CallForwardService_$logistics
```

This lets me to create multiple instances of the same service with different names controlled by the parameter:

[image]